# Repeating a piece of code (not talking about loops) (C)

Tags: c, bgi

```
#include <graphics.h>

int main(){

    int r1;

    int x1;

    int y1;

    printf("Enter the center of the first circle: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &x1, &y1);

    printf("Enter the radius of the first circle: ");

    scanf("%d", &r1);

    int r2;

    int x2;

    int y2;

    printf("Enter the center of the second circle: ");

    scanf("%d%d", &x2, &y2);

    printf("Enter the radius of the second circle: ");

    scanf("%d", &r2);

    if ((abs(x1) + r1 < 321) && (abs(y1) + r1 < 241) && (abs(x2) + r2 < 321) && (abs(y2) + r2 < 241)){

        int gd=DETECT, gm;          //Al deze code is nodig om de cirkel te maken

        initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");

        line(320, 0, 320, 480);

        line(0, 240, 640, 240);

        circle(x1 + 320, y1 + 240, r1);

        circle(x2 + 320, y2 + 240, r2);

        getch();

        closegraph();

    }

    else{

        if ((abs(x1) + r1 >= 321) || (abs(y1) + r1 >= 241))

        {

            printf("Your first circle was to big.");

        }

        if ((abs(x2) + r2 >= 321) || (abs(y2) + r2 >= 241)){

            printf("Your second circle was to big.");

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the circle is too big, you have to restart the program to input something else which may work, but how do I repeat the first few lines of code (where I ask for the user input) when the previous input was too big without copying those lines in an `if` statement.

Comment: You are talking about loops. A loop is the way to “restart” the lines you want.

Comment: *not talking about loops*. Why not? A loop is how something is repeated.

Comment: You can move initialization into a separate function, but the best way to access that function is with a loop (indeed, if you want to access it repeatedly until the input criteria is met, you must use a loop).

Comment: _WHY_ no loops? That's the simplest and the most reasonable way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the forbidden `goto`.

By the way, please read some tutorials about how to format your program in a good way.

Also please read the "Tour" in the "Help Center" to learn how to write a question.

**PS not tested**

**PPS please provide next time a minimal example which may be compiled everywhere**

**PPPS you should rewrite your entire program and check first the user inputs**

```
#include <graphics.h>

int main(){
    int r1, x1, y1, r2, x2, y2;
    int gd = DETECT, gm;          //Al deze code is nodig om de cirkel te maken
    int first_circle_too_big = 0;

FIRSTCIRCLE:
    printf("Enter the center of the first circle: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &x1, &y1);
    printf("Enter the radius of the first circle: ");
    scanf("%d", &r1);
    if(first_circle_too_big){
        first_circle_too_big = 0;
        goto RECHECK;
    }

SECONDCIRCLE:
    printf("Enter the cenPS you should rewrite your entire program and check first the user inputs ter of the second circle: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &x2, &y2);
    printf("Enter the radius of the second circle: ");
    scanf("%d", &r2);
    
RECHECK:
    if ((abs(x1) + r1 < 321) && (abs(y1) + r1 < 241) && (abs(x2) + r2 < 321) && (abs(y2) + r2 < 241)){

        initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");

        line(320, 0, 320, 480);

        line(0, 240, 640, 240);

        circle(x1 + 320, y1 + 240, r1);

        circle(x2 + 320, y2 + 240, r2);

        getch();

        closegraph();

    }

    else{

        if ((abs(x1) + r1 >= 321) || (abs(y1) + r1 >= 241))

        {

            printf("Your first circle was to big.");
            first_circle_too_big = 1;
            goto FIRSTCIRCLE;

        }

        if ((abs(x2) + r2 >= 321) || (abs(y2) + r2 >= 241)){

            printf("Your second circle was to big.");
            goto SECONDCIRCLE;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm very new with C so thank you for your tips!

Comment: @David you may read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture

Answer (score 0):

You *are* talking about loops, you just need to put them before the user input. If the input is invalid, the loop won't break and the user will have to input again. Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter a number between 0 and 10: ");
        scanf("%i", &number);

        if (number >= 0 && number <= 10) {
            break;
        }

        printf("The number is invalid, try again!\n");
    }

    printf("The number '%i' is valid\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and looking at it I think I was talking about loops! hahahaha